# How I Can Display Fetched Data in XML From Database in Odoo 12

Tags: xml, database, odoo-12

I want to display fetched data in XML file in Odoo 12.

I have two questions:

1. How can I fetch required data from database
2. How can I show data in pivot view in xml file in odoo 12

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-fetch-context-value-from-wizard-to-pivot-view-153101

Comment: No it's not working for me.

Comment: You have to provide more details on what you want to achieve.